# Custom format/display of sums of vectors

Tags: output-formatting, vector

The parametric equation of a line is $\vec x=\vec p+t\cdot\vec u$, I want to display this equation "as it is", don't want for Mathematica to simplify it.

```
line[t_,p_,u_]:=p+t u
```

So if I define a line with:

```
line[t,{1,2,3},{-1,0,1}]
(*
  => {1-t,2,3+t}
*)
```

But I want it to display it like the equation, something like this:
$\begin{pmatrix} 1\\2\\3\end {pmatrix}$ +t·$\begin{pmatrix} -1\\0\\1\end {pmatrix}$

I tried:

```
line/:MakeBoxes[parameter_,p_,u_]:=
  RowBox[{GridBox[Transpose[{p}]],"+",MakeBoxes[parameter],"·",GridBox[Transpose[{u}]]}]
```

So the previous command gives the following result:

```
line[t,{1,2,3},{-1,0,1}] //DisplayForm

(*

1   -1
2+t· 0
3    1

*)
```

But I can't get to print the parenthesis around the vectors. Also I get an error if I try to use `MatrixForm` in `MakeBoxes`, like this:

```
line/:MakeBoxes[parameter_,p_,u_]:=
  RowBox[{MakeBoxes[p,MatrixForm],"+",MakeBoxes[parameter],"·",MakeBoxes[u,MatrixForm]}]
```

I get an error that `MatrixForm is not a box formatting type`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Jason Harris's talk at Wolfram Technology Conference 2019, the way to do that is:

```
MakeBoxes[line[
    t_
    , p : _List /; VectorQ @ Unevaluated @ p
    , u :  _List /; VectorQ @ Unevaluated @ u
    ]
   , StandardForm] :=
  With[
   {argsp = Map[Function[{a}, MakeBoxes[a, StandardForm], HoldAll]
      , Unevaluated @ p, {1}]
    , argsu = Map[Function[{a}, MakeBoxes[a, StandardForm], HoldAll]
      , Unevaluated @ u, {1}]}
   , RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[Transpose @ {argsp}], "", ")", "+", 
     MakeBoxes[t, StandardForm], "(", "", 
     GridBox[Transpose @ {argsu}], "", ")"}]
   ];

line[t, {1, 2, 3}, {-1, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I'm a beginner on this subject, so there may be subtelties I'm not aware.

Comment: There are more recent talks from J. Harris on this subject in more recent Wolfram Technology Conferences. They are very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Does this function do what you want?

```
line[t_, p_, u_] := CellPrint[
                          Cell[
                         BoxData[
                            RowBox[
                             {StyleBox[
                                  RowBox[{"(", 
                                         GridBox[
                                            {{ToString[p[[1]]]}
                                            ,{ToString[p[[2]]]}
                                            , {ToString[p[[3]]]}}], 
                                  ")"}]
                                    , FontSize -> 12]
                                    , StyleBox["+", FontSize -> 12]
                                    , RowBox[{StyleBox[ToString[t]
                                    , FontSize -> 12]
                                    , StyleBox[".", FontSize -> 12]
                                    , RowBox[{"("
                                    , GridBox[
                                      {
                                         {RowBox[{ToString[u[[1]]]}]}
                                       , {ToString[u[[2]]]}
                                       , {ToString[u[[3]]]}
                                     }]
                                       , ")"}]}]}]]
                                   , "Output"] ];
```

[image]